# Improve the performance of if-else loop to update missing value

Tags: r, performance, if-statement

I have a massive dataset with millions of lines that I want to fill in the missing values with either the previous value, next value or average of previous and next value available value. It will check for previous three rows and next three rows for availability of non-missing value. Here missing value is represented by -99. I wrote `ifelse` loop for that but it's taking me hours to do this task. Can we accomplish it more efficiently and quickly?

```
rec_30 <- which(data$TEMPERATURE %in% c(-99) & data$MIN == 30)

for(q in rec_30){
    ifelse(q <= 4, aa <- data$TEMPERATURE[q],                                         
           ifelse(data$TEMPERATURE[q-1] > 0, aa <- data$TEMPERATURE[q-1],
                  ifelse(data$TEMPERATURE[q-2] > 0, aa <- data$TEMPERATURE[q-2],
                         ifelse(data$TEMPERATURE[q-3], aa <- data$TEMPERATURE[q-3], aa <- data$TEMPERATURE[q]))))
    
    ifelse(data$TEMPERATURE[q+1] > 0, bb <- data$TEMPERATURE[q+1],
           ifelse(data$TEMPERATURE[q+2] > 0, bb <- data$TEMPERATURE[q+2],
                  ifelse(data$TEMPERATURE[q+3] > 0, bb <- data$TEMPERATURE[q+3], bb <- data$TEMPERATURE[q])))
    
    ifelse(aa > 0 & bb > 0, data$TEMPERATURE[q] <- (aa + bb)/2,
           ifelse(aa > 0 & bb == -99, data$TEMPERATURE[q] <- aa,
                  ifelse(aa == -99 & bb > 0, data$TEMPERATURE[q] <- bb, data$TEMPERATURE[q] <- data$TEMPERATURE[q])))
}
```

Comment: You could work with the `case_when` function from the `dplyr` package. Complexity decreases and readability increases. On another note: `dplyr::if_else` is faster than `base::ifelse` if you don't want to use `case_when`. Yet another option for speed would be the tidyfast package

Comment: Moving windows like this can be very time-consuming in R. Check out the RcppRoll package, which provides efficient window operations implemented in C++. You could also look into using the Rcpp package to implement a C++ based function for your use case.

Comment: I don't think you want to use `dplyr` here, since you are looking for speed. @zephryl suggestion is excellent and likely the fastest; another option is to try `data.table` as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @zephryl suggested, I wrote a function using Rcpp and it was way faster than R function. Below is working Rcpp function for the R loop mentioned in question.

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('DataFrame mean_function(DataFrame input_df, DataFrame row_number){
  
  #include <vector>
  NumericVector parameter = input_df[8];
  NumericVector row_index = row_number[0];
  
  int leni = row_index.size();
  int lenp = parameter.size();  
        
  float aa, bb;
  for (int i=0; i<leni; i++){
    int q = row_index[i];
    if (q <= 4) {
    aa = parameter[q];
    }else if (parameter[q-1] > 0) {
    aa = parameter[q-1];
    }else if (parameter[q-2] > 0) {
    aa = parameter[q-2];
    }else if (parameter[q-3] > 0) {
    aa = parameter[q-3];
    }else {
    aa = parameter[q];
    }

    if(parameter[q+1] > 0) {
    bb = parameter[q+1];
    }else if (parameter[q+2] > 0){
    bb = parameter[q+2];
    }else if (parameter[q+3] > 0) {
    bb = parameter[q+3];
    }else {
    bb = parameter[q];
    }

    if (aa > 0 && bb > 0) {
    parameter[q] = (aa + bb)/2.0;
    }else if (aa > 0 && bb == -99) {
    parameter[q] = aa;
    }else if (aa == -99 && bb > 0) {
    parameter[q] = bb;
    }else {
    parameter[q] = parameter[q];
    }

   for (int x=0; x< lenp; x++)
   {
   if(x==q)
   parameter[x]=parameter[q];
   else
   parameter[x]=parameter[x];
   }
  }
   
DataFrame Updated_Variable = DataFrame::create(Named("up_value") = parameter);
return(Updated_Variable);

}')

mean_function(data, rec_30)
```

Here  `NumericVector parameter = input_df[8]` selects 9th column from dataframe `data` and I `rec_30` is converted to dataframe instaed of list.

I hope it helps someone in future.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a an option that leverages `data.table::shift()`

1. set your data to data.table, and change -99 to NA

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[TEMPERATURE==-99, TEMPERATURE:=NA]
```

2. Create columns for the previous three temp values and the next temp values and an `id` column for subsequent evaluation by row.

```
cols = c(paste0("next",1:3), paste0("prior",1:3))
data[,(cols):= shift(TEMPERATURE, c(-1:-3,1:3))]
data[, id:=.I]
```

3. use `fcase` by row to get the correct combination of next/prev for each row

```
data[is.na(TEMPERATURE), IMPUTED_TEMPERATURE:=fcase(
  any(next1,prior1), mean(c(next1,prior1), na.rm=T),
  any(next2,prior2), mean(c(next2,prior2), na.rm=T),
  any(next3,prior3), mean(c(next3,prior3), na.rm=T),
  default=NA), id][, (c(cols,"id")):=NULL]
```

Here is alternative approach that would replace steps 2 and 3 above. It uses `rowMeans`. Note that I call `shift()` three times here, each time for the set of +/-1 row, +/-2 rows, +/-3 rows (but this can be further simplified if you want to take the mean of any and all values that are available in the 3 rows before and 3 rows after)

```
# Get the three sets of rowmeans
rmeans = cbind(
  rowMeans(data[, shift(TEMPERATURE, c(-1,1))], na.rm=T),
  rowMeans(data[, shift(TEMPERATURE, c(-2,2))], na.rm=T),
  rowMeans(data[, shift(TEMPERATURE, c(-3,3))], na.rm=T)
)
# Set imputed temperature to the first one that is not NA
data[, imputed:=apply(rmeans,1,\(x) x[which(!is.na(x))[1]])]

# Set imputed back to NA if it does  not need to be imputed
data[!is.na(TEMPERATURE), imputed:=NA]
```

Output (first 10 rows; same with either method)

```
    TEMPERATURE IMPUTED_TEMPERATURE
          <num>               <num>
 1:    21.13703                  NA
 2:          NA            23.61489
 3:    26.09275                  NA
 4:    26.23379                  NA
 5:    28.60915                  NA
 6:          NA            24.35206
 7:    20.09496                  NA
 8:    22.32551                  NA
 9:          NA            23.73401
10:    25.14251                  NA
```

Input:

```
data = structure(list(TEMPERATURE = c(21.1370341130532, -99, 26.0927473288029, 
26.2337944167666, 28.6091538355686, -99, 20.0949575635605, 22.3255050601438, 
-99, 25.1425114134327, -99, 25.4497483558953, 22.8273358359002, 
29.2343348427676, 22.9231584025547, 28.3729562815279, -99, 22.6682078000158, 
-99, -99, -99, 23.0269337072968, 21.590460028965, 20.3999591805041, 
22.1879954100586, 28.1059855245985, -99, -99, 28.3134504687041, 
-99, 24.5609148242511, -99, 23.0467220302671, 25.0730687007308, 
-99, -99, 22.0124803762883, 22.5880981865339, 29.9215041752905, 
28.0735234031454, -99, -99, -99, 26.2181919813156, 23.2977017574012, 
25.0199747295119, 26.7709452728741, -99, 22.4392882734537, 27.6545978756621, 
-99, 23.0968660186045, -99, 25.0454591214657, 21.5299895894714, 
25.0393348815851, -99, -99, 21.7464982392266, -99, -99, 20.4185727518052, 
-99, 20.137499391567, -99, -99, 23.0809475714341, 25.0854756566696, 
20.5164661933668, -99, -99, -99, 20.1462725573219, -99, 20.899613329675, 
-99, -99, 20.7005249732174, -99, -99, -99, 24.7190972114913, 
21.4261534321122, -99, -99, 28.9858048921451, 23.8949978468008, 
23.1087077967823, -99, 28.9618584956042, 21.6639378038235, 29.0042459615506, 
21.3407819508575, 21.3161413418129, 21.0528750251979, 25.1158358110115, 
23.0019905394875, -99, 23.0964743136428, 27.4211965710856)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This code is not working with your data also. It's giving error and only creating ```next1```, ```next2```, ```next3```, ```prior1```, ```prior2```, & ```prior3``` columns.

Comment: apologies. fixed. code works now. Previously was `TEMPERATURE=fcase(...)`, but must be `TEMPERATURE:=fcase(...)`

Comment: Is it assigning the same value everywhere?  I checked with your data where it assigns same value for all missing values. I want to assign either leading available value or previous available or if both available then mean of them from previous and leading 3 rows.

Comment: you are right, I'm not being careful enough today! - added by row, to ensure this is done by row.

Comment: Also, if you have all three prev and all three next, and you are willing to use the mean of all six of those values, (or the mean of any/all of the six posible values), this can be simplified greatly using `rowMeans`

Comment: Added another faster method, that uses `rowMeans`

Comment: Is there any syntax error in ```data[, imputed:=apply(rmeans,1,\(x) x[which(!is.na(x))[1]])]```, I'm getting error ```Error: unexpected input in "data[, imputed:=apply(rmeans,1,\"``` with your data.

Comment: doesn't look like any error to me.. Perhaps you have R version prior to 4.1? Only 4.1 and beyond allow the shortcut `\(x)` inplace of `function(x)`.. If you have an early version of R, try `function(x)`